# How Do I Get Citibank To Give Me My Money?

Tags: banking, bank-account, deposits

I was banking with Citibank online back in August. I was a good customer. I never went in the negative and I was very nice to all employees.  I have my own business and  I receive at least 7 to 10 checks a month.

I deposited a check and when it did not clear, I called the bank to find out why.  They told me that the check was bad and if it happens again,  they would close my account.  I told her that I had two checks from the same person and that the other one hadn't come through yet.

The other check finally hit my account and they closed it without informing me. When I found out,  I asked about the money in my account. They said that I would get a letter in the mail and I would get a check for what I had left in my account, subject to a waiting period of  60 days so they could take out anything I owed them (but I didn't owe them anything).

I had $700 dollars in the account.  It went down to $500 then $400 and the last time I spoke with them,  I had $287 left. They still have not sent me the money  and they  keep saying that another division in there company has it and they don't know where it and   don't know  how to get it back. I have spoken with manager after manager and no one has a answer.

I don't know what to do and I rally need my money.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Get a lawyer. If you can't afford a lawyer then I guess talk to the police and file a report or go to whomever they direct you to.

Comment: @Lawrence:  I edited out the all caps stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Banks, typically, do not just steal money from your account.  There are notable exceptions to this but in general that is not the case.  However, what they will do is penalize you for misbehaving and depositing checks that will not clear is one form of misbehavior.

In your case, it sounds like you have $700 in your account if all the checks you deposited cleared.  However, two checks did not clear and they closed your account as they said they would.  There would be fees associated with those bad checks and it is perfectly reasonable to assume that your balance is now down to $287.  Were there other checks deposited that were also bad?

From August to December (now) you presumably received between 35 and 50 checks.  What did you do with those?  Where did you deposit them?  It would seem that the total of those checks would be far more than the $287 that remains at Citibank.  A better option would be for you to cash those checks at the originating bank.  There is usually a fee with this kind of service, which I think is unjust, but that is the way it is.  This way you will know if a check is good or not.

Eventually Citibank will get this straitened out.  You will just have to be persistent.

To me, the gist of this question screams of you being involved with some kind of check cashing fraud or you are being scammed.  In that case, this money was not yours to begin with and as such you cannot expect it to be returned.